# How to look values within given range in cell where IF is run

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to develop a limitation on a F2 cell which has IF statement in it. IF statement needs to be executed first and only then limitation should come in place. Current IF statement adds two different variables from table and brings back the result.

I can only accept result from 2 to 7 on F2 cell. Meaning result of 1.2 should not be shown and cell should return 2. As well it can't exceed value of 7.

Be aware that B3 has dropdown meaning inputs in table will change accordingly.

[image: Example]

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: What do you mean ? is problem unclear for you ?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Try to improve your question by providing [mcve], example data input (not screenshot), expected versus actual results. Take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips on how to improve the question.

Comment: `limitation on a cell` sounds like the [Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) feature - there is also a **Examples of formulas in data validation** section,, but other than that I have no idea what you are asking here

Comment: I have tried to simplify the question. Does it make sense now ?

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps?

```
=IF(B3="A",
      MAX(
            MIN(
                  INDEX($L$2:$L$11,LARGE(($I$2:$I$11="CLASS")*($J$2:$J$11=E2)*($K$2:$K$11<=$B$5)*ROW($L$2:$L$11),1))+
                  INDEX($L$2:$L$11,LARGE(($I$2:$I$11="VAKD")*($J$2:$J$11=E2)*($K$2:$K$11<=$B$6)*ROW($L$2:$L$11),1))
            ,7)
      ,2)
)
```

CONFIRMED with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Answer (score 0):

lets assume your formula works with the exception of the limitations of 2 and 7 boundaries.  Take your formula and nest it inside a MAX and MIN formula.  It should look something like:

```
=MIN(your formula,7)
```

so when your formula tries to return a value greater than 7, the minimum function will return a value of 7 because it is lower.  Now to cover the case where your formula returns a value less than 2, we nest the formula above in a MAX:

```
=MAX(MIN(your formula,7),2)
```